# Microservices Contract Testing based on gRPC and Go

Tags: go, microservices, grpc

Are there any tools like `Pact.io` available, or **any** **workaround** to perform `contract testing` between two microservices?

My use case:

I have my microservices written in `GoLang` and it is communicating to the other services via `gRPC protocol`. There is another microservice, may be written in `Python`, but again communicating via gRPC.
If I can get my protobufs ready, how do I perform a contract test between these microservices?

Also, in such a scenario, can we have contracts created automatically, or written manually?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking to perform integration testing here?  Or are you trying to individually test each client and/or server component?  With gRPC, you'll end up with client and server code generated for any supported language binding which makes it quite easy to mock a client or server to individually test components.

Comment: @GariSingh Hi, Thanks! I am heading to investigate on both, integration testing and testing microservices individually. I understand that mocking would become easy with gRPC. That is when I would test my microservice with the mock of a different microservice. But what if I have the 2 microservices ready in place. Can I have testing between them? Or is Contract Testing not even required here?